# Grabbing the list item TextView value when ContextMenu is opened

Tags: android, android-listview, contextmenu, textview

On a `ListView` single/short click, I can do this:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    tvInt = reviews.get(position);
}
```

How would I do this for a `ContextMenu`? My `ListView` simply contains a single `TextView`.

Edit: I want to grab the value of the `TextView` in the `ListView`, not the `ContextMenu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MenuItem` packs extra information from where you could extract the `position` of the clicked row in the `ListView` and then simply use the code you used in the `onListItemClick` callback:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
     int clickedPosition = info.position;
     tvInt = reviews.get(position);
     // ...
```

The same information, `ContextMenuInfo`, is available in the `onCreateContextMenu` callback if you want to get the String when building the `ContextMenu`.